# Polynomials in one variable simple module here or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be the $k$-algebra of differential operators with polynomial coefficients in one variable, where $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$. I know that $k[t]$ has a natural $A$-module structure.

**Question.** Is $k[t]$ a simple $A$-module or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

For a bit more detail, note that $A$ is the $k$-algebra generated by two elements $x$ and $d$ with the relation $dx-xd=1$ (here you should think of $d=\partial/\partial x$). Then, $k[t]$ is an $A$-module where $x$ acts as multiplication by $t$, and $d$ acts by $\partial/\partial t$.

To show that $k[t]$ is simple, suppose $V\subset k[t]$ is an $A$-submodule. We will show that either $V=0$ or $V=k[t]$. Indeed, if $V\neq 0$, then there exists some
$$f(t)=a_nt^n+\cdots+a_0\in V$$
with $a_n\neq 0$. Note that
$$\frac{1}{a_n}d^n.f(t)=1\in V$$
and now, for any $g(t)\in k[t]$, $g(x).1=g(t)\in V$. Hence $V=k[t]$ as required.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! One point of confusion: why does it follow that the $k$-algebra with $2$ generators $y$, $z$, and $1$ defining relation $zy - yz = 1$ you mentioned above is isomorphic to $A$?

Comment: Well, there is some work to be done. The algebra $A$ you describe is certainly generated by $x$ and $d:=\partial/\partial x$ as every element can be written as $\sum a_{n,m}x^nd^m$. You should check that $x$ and $d$ satisfy the given relation (consider the left regular module and act on $1$). Therefore, if $W$ is the abstract algebra given by generators $y,z$ subject to $zy-yz=1$ you get a surjective map $W\to A$ given by $z\mapsto d$ and $y\mapsto x$. If you show that $W$ has basis $y^nz^m$, you are done.